# Merge A Group of PDF Files Into One PDF File On A Per Folder Basis, So Once The Files In One Folder Are Merged Automatically Go To Next Folder Do Same

Tags: pdf, merge, adobe, workflow

I have numerous folder structures with a label name on each folder. Within each of the these folders there are are 11 individual pdfs. I have to merge these pdfs into one file. Then I move onto the next folder (which contains files for a different project, but same report format) and merge all these files into a single file. Does anyone know of an automated way to do this. Could powerautomate be utilized to accomplish this? Or can it be done directly in Adobe? I have to do this hundred of time and looking to improve the workflow.

I am not sure where to begin on this. I am looking into PowerAutomate but I havent been given adobe yet. Currently using Xodo by hand to drag and drop the documents.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are a programmer or have access to a programmer, you could consider writing code to go through each sub-folder and perform this merging. For example, it is very easy to do this using the LEADTOOLS PDF File Library. The library has the [MergeFiles](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdffile-mergefiles.html) method which can be used to accomplish this. You can download a free evaluation from [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)